# Which Trek character says 'Live Long and Prosper' the most?

Tags: star-trek

The phrase 'Live Long and Prosper' is probably *the* most iconic phrase of *Star Trek*.  So my question is **which *Star Trek* character says the phrase 'Live Long and Prosper' the most times?**

Comment: Do we have reason to believe this is anyone other than Spock?

Comment: @Kevin we did, then the universe introduced a new law whereby 9 > 8, meaning that there is no tie.  Go back to your stations everyone; nothing to worry about here!

Comment: How can we possibly know?   I mean,  99.999% of their lives are not shown on screen.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that the OP is talking about known Star Trek characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Spock: 9 times

- *Star Trek 2009* (Spock Prime)
- *TOS* 'The Savage Curtain'
- *The Voyage Home* (twice)
- *TAS* 'Yesteryear'
- *Wrath of Khan*
- *TOS* 'Is There In Truth No Beauty?'
- *TOS* 'Assignment: Earth'
- *TOS* 'Amok Time'

and in a very close second place comes

## Tuvok: 8 times

- *VOY* 'Revulsion'
- *VOY* 'Year of Hell'
- *VOY* 'Resolutions'
- *VOY* 'Homestead' (twice)
- *VOY* 'Counterpoint'
- *VOY* 'Gravity'
- *VOY* 'Shattered

Comment: I think it's safe to say that Worf is not third.